# How to pass a type to a generic method for deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, xamarin

I would like to pass a string and a type to a generic method and attempt to  deserialize. Here is what I've got:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value, Type type)
{
    T result = default(T);

    try
    {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<type>(value);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"\nDeserialization Success! : { result }\n");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"\nDeserialization failed with exception : { ex }\n");
    }

    return result;
}
```

My attempt to call the method where 'GroupObject' is the type I would like to return:

```
var deserialized = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject(value: response, type: GroupObject);
```

Results in an Error:

```
Error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected (CS0119)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Your method doesn't use the `type` variable.

Additionally, to call the method with a type parameter you use the `typeof` function:

```
var deserialized = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject(value: response, type: typeof(GroupObject));
```

Granted, you don't provide much information here, but in my experience you are looking for a method more like this:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
{
    T result = default(T);
    try {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

to be called like:

```
var deserialized = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject<GroupObject>(value: response);
```

Comment: The reason I am including the type as a parameter is I would like to use the same method to deserialize objects of other specific types

Comment: `var deserialized = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject<ANY_TYPE_YOU_WANT_GOES_HERE>(value: response);`  Sounds like you should read up on generics.

Comment: I want to be able to specify the type when I call the method. I will always be passing in a string but sometimes I want it to return a CompanyObject and other times I want to return a GroupObject / SomeOtherObject.

Comment: I fixed a typo in my original question. Im not trying to deserialize to <T>, instead I want to deserialize to <type> the type passed as an argument to the method.

Comment: Well that would be very silly as your return type is `<T>` and you can not guarantee that `type` and `<T>` will look anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `type` parameter at all if I understood you correctly. You have a generic already and can do

```
GroupObject deserialized = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject<GroupObject>(response)
```

This will work with any other class as well, e.g.

```
Foo foo = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject<Foo>(response)
```

P.S. I don't see that you use `type` actually.

Comment: I would like to use it like this : Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject<type>(response) so I can reuse the method to deserialize objects of other types

Comment: Yes, you can do that already. You just need to pass any type you want in brackets `<AnyType>`. This is how the generics work

Answer (score 0):

You actually not using parameter `type` in the method at all. You don't actually need that parameter. You can remove that parameter from the method.

ethod and attempt to deserialize. Here is what I've got:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value)
{
    T result = default(T);

    try
    {
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"\nDeserialization Success! : { result }\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"\nDeserialization failed with exception : { ex }\n");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string inputString)
{
    T result = default(T);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputString)))
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

            result = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

            WriteLine($"\nDeserialization Success : { result }\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLine($"\nDeserialization Failed With Exception : { ex }\n");
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The 'type' is included in the method call:

```
var deserialized = Core.Deserializer.DeserializeObject<GroupObject>(value: response);
```